# Vim: How to change the highlight color for search hits and quickfix selection

Tags: colors, vim

I am using the desert colorscheme, which uses white text on orange background for highlighting search hits. The same pattern is used for the selected entry in the quickfix window.

White on orange is not very readable. How do I change that in .vimrc?

**Edit:** Thanks for the fast reply, for the desert scheme I am now using the following search highlight modification:

```
highlight Search guibg='Purple' guifg='NONE'
```

Purple is quite easy to detect visually and it is IMHO not used for syntax coloring in the desert scheme.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Look at `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/desert.vim`.  Color mappings are defined there with the `hi[ghlight]` command.  The search highlighting is defined as

```
hi Search guibg=peru guifg=wheat
```

for the GUI and

```
hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=blue
```

for terminals.

You can override this setting in your `.vimrc` using the same command after you select your `colorscheme`.  Type `:h hi` for help.

Comment: Hey! You just gave me another hint. I've always used :help instead of :h ;)

Comment: I've found the torte color scheme to fir my needs nicely.

:colorscheme torte

Comment: You may also need to `:set hlsearch` if your search results aren't being highlighted at all.

Comment: To do this once for your current vim session and not persist changes, just run it in ex mode (`:`) in front of the `hi` command: `:hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=blue`

Comment: I can see this highlights all the instances. How do you change the highlight of the instance you're cursor is currently on?

Comment: @Costa see [this Q&A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2761/25983) or any of these plugins: [vim-searchlight](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-searchlight), [vim-searchhi](https://github.com/qxxxb/vim-searchhi), [vim-searchant](https://github.com/timakro/vim-searchant). searchlight is like searchhi but with the goal of requiring no configuration. additionally, you might use a terminal emulator that dynamically changes the cursor color according to the color of the text behind/below it, which isn't a full match solution, but at least provides some visual cues.

Answer (score 80):

For me I have to also add **hlsearch** under `syntax on` in the `~/.vimrc`

```
set hlsearch
hi Search ctermbg=LightYellow
hi Search ctermfg=Red
```

Inside VIM you can also do: `:highlight Search ctermfg=yellow` to change it on the fly.

- `ctermfg` is for foreground color
- `ctermbg` is for background color

available colors from the [vi documentation page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) are:

```
*cterm-colors*

NR-16   NR-8    COLOR NAME 
0       0       Black
1       4       DarkBlue
2       2       DarkGreen
3       6       DarkCyan
4       1       DarkRed
5       5       DarkMagenta
6       3       Brown, DarkYellow
7       7       LightGray, LightGrey, Gray, Grey
8       0*      DarkGray, DarkGrey
9       4*      Blue, LightBlue
10      2*      Green, LightGreen
11      6*      Cyan, LightCyan
12      1*      Red, LightRed
13      5*      Magenta, LightMagenta
14      3*      Yellow, LightYellow
15      7*      White
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case the line in the QuickFix window was showing an unreadable grey on cyan, which was different to my search results (a more pleasing black on peach)
This was confirmed by the command

```
:hi
```

which showed the formatting of `QuickFixLine` and `Search` as being set to

```
QuickFixLine   xxx term=reverse guibg=Cyan
Search         xxx term=reverse ctermfg=0 ctermbg=222 guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFE792
```

where `xxx` had a sample format,

I appended the following line to my `~/.vimrc`

```
hi QuickFixLine term=reverse ctermbg=52
```

and now in my terminal window I have a more pleasing dark red background. Running `hi:` shows the addition of the background colour change for my ternimal:

```
QuickFixLine   xxx term=reverse ctermbg=52 guibg=Cyan
```

(vim 8 on MacOS High Sierra in iTerm2, with molokai theme)